# Create a WKWebView in a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, wkwebview

I'm trying to add a WKWebView inside of a UIView ,

The code seems to work fine ( the page is loaded the bounds is good the delegate print the message with no error)
but the View (called ViewForStuffInWeb ) stay blank, nothing in it 
 can someone explain why ?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController ,WKNavigationDelegate  {


@IBOutlet var ViewForStuffInWeb: UIView!

var webView = WKWebView()
let request =  "https://www.google.fr"



override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: ViewForStuffInWeb.bounds ,configuration : config)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    ViewForStuffInWeb = webView
    println("webview : frame :\(webView.frame)  , bounds : \(webView.bounds)")
    requesting(request)
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func requesting (request :String) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: request) {
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    }

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    println("decide policy action")
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow)
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationResponse navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {
    println("decide policy response")
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicy.Allow)
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didCommitNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    println("commit navigation")
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
    println("fail in didFailNavigation \(error)")
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: NSError) {
    println("fail in didFailProvisionalNavigation \(error)")
}
func webView(webView: WKWebView, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    println("finish navigation")
}
```

thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never add the `WKWebView` to the view hierarchy. In your `viewDidAppear`, which code should really move to `viewDidLoad`, you probably want to replace:

```
ViewForStuffInWeb = webView
```

with:

```
ViewForStuffInWeb.addSubview(webView)
```

Although it is unclear what `ViewForStuffInWeb` actually is. The above will only work if that view exists in your nib and if it is connected.